# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV (0xb)

Tags: java

I am using RHEL 6 with 64 bit OS. For one of my application I had installed “jre-6u23-linux-x64.bin”. When I execute my application I am getting the below ERROR:

```
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003222414d70, pid=4977, tid=140076581496592
 # JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 # Problematic frame:**
 # C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x14d70]
 # An error report file with more information is saved as
 # /root/Desktop/Madhu/SELVIEW10.0-B4/Linux/hs_err_pid4977.log
 # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Can anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Please fix formatting. And, tell us what are you trying to do when this happens. And if possible the error log.

Comment: Have you looked at the log? (/root/Desktop/Madhu/SELVIEW10.0-B4/Linux/hs_err_pid4977.log)

Answer (score 4):

Between

> The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

and

> An error report file with more information is saved as
>   /root/Desktop/Madhu/SELVIEW10.0-B4/Linux/hs_err_pid4977.log

it looks like you're dealing with a defective native library. Have a look at that hs_err dump (it's plain text), it should point to the problem.

Another thing to try: the Compressed OOPS optimization was added to the JVM fairly recently, try disabling that (pass `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` on the command line) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I already did: pass `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is also discussed here: [community.oracle.com thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2561823)

The suggested solution is to set LD_BIND_NOW=1:

```
export LD_BIND_NOW=1
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar yourapp.jar
```

Comment: This doesn't seem related to my environment. I am running confluence local dev environment and problem still persists. I am using Apache Tomcat as server to run confluence and there is no trace of Generic WebLogic Server.